# Salesforce Health Cloud - Reviews?

Tags: documentation, cloud, health-cloud

Has anyone had a chance to implement Salesforce's **[Health Cloud](http://www.salesforce.com/industries/healthcare/health-cloud/)**? There is very limited documentation about Health Cloud and its limitations.  Would love to hear their reviews about Health Cloud implementation. If I'm doing a CRM for an hospital/clinic, should I go with Sales Cloud or Health Cloud?

To narrow down the topic.  Here are my basic questions

1. Is there any documentation comparing the Health Cloud with any other Salesforce clouds?
2. What are the limitations of Health Cloud in terms of integrations?
3. Does Health Cloud by default come with Service Cloud features too? (This [Healthcloud datasheet](https://secure.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/industries/healthcloud-datasheet.pdf) suggests so, but need confirmation)

Comment: Even after narrowing  the question it still seems very broad and opinion based. Its interesting question though.

Comment: Also how can we compare Health Cloud with any other Salesforce clouds? it would be comparing orange and apple.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Thanks for the comment.  By comparision, I mean something like what features does Health Cloud provide which do not exist in other clouds.

Comment: Can you give any example?